# Trying to install PEAR (running go-pear batch file) - getting "php_pdo.dll is missing" error

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, batch-file, pear

I need PEAR installed. So, I tried running the `go-pear` batch file inside by PHP extract. But it gives this error -

```
The program can't start because php_pdo.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this.
```

But I have that `dll` file inside `\ext` folder. My environment variables have the path `D:\php5` (I added it) and in my php.ini I have the following paths -

```
include_path =".;D:\php5\PEAR"
extension_dir = "D:\php5\ext"
```

Which are all valid. And I have the `php_pdo.dll` file present inside `D:\php5\ext`.

Any pointers guys?

**Further details**
I have a 64-bit system with Windows 7 running. I took PHP 5.2.17 VC6 from http://windows.php.net/download/ -> VC6 x86 Thread Safe. It worked fine. 
- Then I took the php.ini file of a teammate (having PHP version 5.3.6) and overwrote mine. He has his system completely setup and I am setting up mine. Earlier I had simply copied his PHP installation folder but later got problems like -

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\php5\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

The problem got fixed by taking a fresh PHP download. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/1343514/351903 for a similar issue.

- Okay, now, after taking the fresh download, I needed to have all the project specific config changes like my teammate, for which I need to have PEAR installed, which is why I was trying to run that batch file.

Comment: Just to put a note of precaution here - **do not copy php.ini files across different PHP versions**. I know most people would not do this, but still :) After doing that, many php extension dlls were not loading. Got many errors like - `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\php5\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`